# Srch.U.getArray() Alternate delimiter

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering, ctx

I have a list field (str) but it contains a list of items.
Problem is, it's a field for legacy categories, and some use "," some use "|" while others use ";".

Currently, the following works on all fields using ";"

```
var cats = Srch.U.getArray(ctx.CurrentItem.Categories);
console.log(cats);
```

Looks like:

> ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"]

Any fields using "|" look like

> ["Cat1|Cat2|Cat3"]

I've tried appending a delimiter parameter to the getArray method but it does nothing.

```
var cats = Srch.U.getArray(ctx.CurrentItem.Categories,"|");
```

or

```
var cats = Srch.U.getArray(ctx.CurrentItem.Categories,",");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srch.U.getArray - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn768314.aspx

*Execute `Srch.U.getArray.toString()` in the F12 Dev Console to read the function definition:*

```
function (a) {
    if (Srch.U.e(a)) return a;  // Null or Empty string
    if (a.indexOf(",#") >= 0) return a.split(",#");
    else if (a.indexOf(" | ") >= 0) return Srch.ValueInfo.Renderers.parseUserFieldValue(a).split(",");
    return a.split(";")
}
```

`Srch.U.getArray(a)` only splits on one separator,  *based on the syntax it finds in the String*

There is no second parameter,
and defaults to **;** if the string is not a SharePoint Lookup or SharePoint Person string

#### split the string with multiple separators

So instead of using that Microsoft wrapper function, write your own code..
it's shorter, faster, and more versatile

```
"Cat1,Cat2|Cat3;Cat4".split(/[,|;]/)
```

will split (using a Regular Expression) on any of the three separators  **, | ;**
(*ofcourse these should not be regular characters in your item values then*)

```
►["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4"]
```

It is not uncommon to have whitespace in data

```
"Cat1, Cat2| Cat3 ; Cat4".split(/\s*[,|;]\s*/)
```

removes whitespace before and after an item

```
►["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear, concise answer! This was Tremendously helpful.